# How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have success with outline custom styling when `variant="outlined"` and I use `notchedOutline` in `InputProps`.

Otherwise - `variant=[anything else]` where only a bottom border exists - it doesn't work, even with `underline` as the key/class in `InputProps`.

I've even tried `root`.

```js
export default ({ boxType, classes, value, onChange, style }) => (
  <TextField
    variant={boxType || "standard"}
    value={value}
    onChange={onChange}
    InputProps={{
      classes: {
        notchedOutline: classes.notchedOutline,
        underline: classes.underline,
        root: classes.TextInputField
      },
      style
    }}
  />
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to determine how to do this, it is helpful to look at how the default styling is done within [Input](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js).

`:before` is used for the default and hover styling and `:after` is used for the focused styling.

Here is a working example of how to style it:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { withStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const styles = {
  underline: {
    "&:before": {
      borderBottom: "2px solid green"
    },
    "&:hover:not($disabled):not($focused):not($error):before": {
      borderBottom: "2px solid blue"
    },
    "&:after": {
      borderBottom: "3px solid purple"
    }
  },
  disabled: {},
  focused: {},
  error: {}
};
function App({ classes }) {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TextField InputProps={{ classes }} />
    </div>
  );
}
const StyledApp = withStyles(styles)(App);
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<StyledApp />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField underline]

Comment: Methinks you're on to something :-) . Gimme a bit.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

You can just use 
`InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}`.It will disable the underLine of textField in all cases. 
Tested on react-material-ui version 3 and above.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which version of material-ui you are using, but you can override classes as needed, see the following API documentation:

https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/#demos

https://material-ui.com/api/outlined-input/

Comment: There is no class in that list which targets the `underline`.