# Material UI: change underline color of Input when hovering

Tags: material-ui

Actually it is not clear from documentation what is the way for changing underline color for Input component on hover. By default underline color is black when hovering on element so it would be great if someone can share the proper of way of handling this case

Note: I know how to solve it with `withStyles` but it is critical for me to avoid it

**Please do not suggest me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme) answer as my request a little bit different**

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-2l6nq

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme)

Comment: @RyanCogswell Why is it duplicate?  As you can see they use `styled-component` approach but in my case I shouldn't do so

Comment: How is your question different? There is very little difference between using `withStyles` and `makeStyles`. Here is a modified version of your sandbox that applies the solution from my other answer: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-l5o9w

Comment: @RyanCogswell thank you

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @RyanCogswell, here is the [answer](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-l5o9w)