# Customize link hover underline highlight material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to follow [material-ui custom styles](https://material-ui.com/customization/components/) and [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme) but am not sure how to override `classes` and use `withStyles`

```js
      <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb" separator=" " className="menu">
        <Link color="inherit" href="/home">
          Home
        </Link>
      </Breadcrumbs>
```

I've modified global `app.css` file

```css
a:hover{
  border-bottom: 1px solid red
}
```

And the outcome is like

```sh
Home
----
----  <- I have 2 underlines now when hovering over the link. The bottom one will be red.
```

How do I override this such as following?

```sh
Home
---- <- only 1 red underline shown when hovering over the link
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that a `Link` is an `<a>` tag, I think what you need to override is text-decoration-color, not border-bottom. Additionally, to make your styling a bit more specific, you can give the `Link` a `className` and define styles for that class.

## Component:

```
  <Breadcrumbs aria-label="breadcrumb" separator=" " className="menu">
    <Link className="custom-link" to="/">
      Home
    </Link>
  </Breadcrumbs>
```

## Style:

```
.custom-link:hover {
  color: red;
  text-decoration-color: red;
}
```

See working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-bush-wpn4m

Comment: @jen007 hmm thats so strange. I've made a sandbox where its working, but your might look different. Do you want to share it?

Comment: Oh that works, I just have to remove `color:red` since it also changes the color of the text. Thanks!!

Comment: Oh you're welcome! I figured they might as well match ahha. Please consider marking this as the solution if you found this helpful. I think making a class is better practice instead of targeting all a tags directly. If you target all a tags, 
and find that you might want others to be a different color, that just creates more work to update. @jen007

Answer (score 13):

For those not doing it through CSS but rather classes, you could do

```
link: {
    color: "#00ff00",
    "&:hover": {
        color: "#000000",
        textDecoration: "underline #000000"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 4):

Provide Material UI with a custom theme, as documented [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theming/).

The relevant bits for link hover underlining are:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const myTheme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiLink: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          textDecoration: "none",
          ":hover": {
            textDecoration: "underline",
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by the other answer the code would surely be

```html
a {  
  text-decoration-color: red;  
}
```

There are two ways you can get this to work:

- Declare the anchor tag styling in index.css and applying it over the whole web-app like you have done.
- Or you could declare it in the style object that you pass while using withStyles HOC. If it helps, you can wrap the Link tag in a div and apply the styles on that div. This will keep the change local, and the Link tag will inherit the property from its parent div.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the answers that address changing this globally (which doesn't seem to be what was asked, but was how I ended up here), the MUI Way is to override the default props for `MuiLink` in your theme. For example:

```js
export const muiTheme = responsiveFontSizes(
  createTheme({
    components: {
      MuiLink: {
        defaultProps: {
          underline: "hover",
        },
        styleOverrides: {
          underlineHover: {
            "&:hover": {
              textDecorationColor: "red",
            },
          },
        },
      },
    },
  })
);
```