# How to customize material-ui TextField Input underline:after?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material-ui for React.

I am trying to customize the color of the underline that transitions into place when the user clicks the Mui `<TextField>` component, which is a result of jss injecting the following CSS:

```
.MuiInput-underline:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid #303f9f;
}
```

I am already invested into styled-components theme provider and do not want to bring in the MuiTheme provider in order to use `createMuiTheme` and `override`.

I have used styled-components to override styling for many other Mui components, but have been unable to override `.MuiInput-underline:after` using styled-components.

I am now trying to use Mui's withStyles, but am unsure of the exact style semantics. I've been unsuccessful using InputProps and using classes.

```
const styles = theme => ({
  inputProps: {
    underline: {
      '&:after': {
        border: '2px solid red'
      }
    }
  }
});

const MyTextField = props => {
  const { classes, ...rest } = props;

  return (
    <TextField InputProps={{ inputProps: classes.inputProps }} {...rest} />
  );
};

export default withStyles(styles)(MyTextField);
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to omit the inputProps key in styles object. 
You also need to provide classses Prop to InputProps:

```
 const styles = theme => ({
    underline: {
      color: 'red' ,
      '&::after': {
        border: '2px solid red'
      }
    }
 });

 const MyTextField = props => {
   const { classes, ...rest } = props;
   return (
     <TextField InputProps={{ classes: {underline: classes.underline} }} {...rest} />
   );
 };
```

You can check this working code sandbox example: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-75w7p?fontsize=14

Answer (score 6):

Here's an example of how to customize the underline using `styled-components`:

```
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import styled from "styled-components";

const StyledTextField = styled(TextField)`
  /* default */
  .MuiInput-underline:before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid green;
  }
  /* hover (double-ampersand needed for specificity reasons. */
  && .MuiInput-underline:hover:before {
    border-bottom: 2px solid lightblue;
  }
  /* focused */
  .MuiInput-underline:after {
    border-bottom: 2px solid red;
  }
`;

export default StyledTextField;
```

[image: Edit TextField underline styled-components]

Related answers:

- [How can I remove the underline of TextField from Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914368/how-can-i-remove-the-underline-of-textfield-from-material-ui/57915357#57915357)
- [How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme/56026253#56026253)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using withStyles.

```
const MyTextField = withStyles((theme: Theme) => ({
  root: {
    "& label.Mui-focused": {
      color: theme.palette.primary.dark
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:before": {
      borderBottomColor: "green"
    },
    "& .MuiInput-underline:after": {
      borderBottomColor: "green"
    },
    "& .MuiInputBase-root": {
      "& fieldset": {
        borderColor: "red"
      },
      "&:hover fieldset": {
        borderColor: "yellow"
      },
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
      }
    },
    "& .MuiOutlinedInput-root": {
      "& fieldset": {
        borderColor: "red"
      },
      "&:hover fieldset": {
        borderColor: "yellow"
      },
      "&.Mui-focused fieldset": {
        borderColor: theme.palette.primary.main
      }
    }
  }
}))(TextField);
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-c2opb?file=/demo.tsx