# How can I remove the underline of TextField from Material-UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I want the TextField to be naked(no underline) when using material-ui TextField. I do know that using InputBase from material-ui can achieve this, but I kinda need to use TextField API to achieve this but i did not find the way to do it in the API guide.

Comment: Just remove the `variant` attribute, it's right in [the documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/text-fields/#customized-inputs) labeled "Naked Input".

Comment: @ChrisW. The "Naked Input" example is using `InputBase` directly (not `TextField`) -- the exact solution the question mentions wanting to avoid.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Even though this is currently the accepted answer, please see the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61185770/7495930) instead (using the `disableUnderline` prop). I wrote this answer after having recently written an answer about how to customize the underline (which uses approaches similar to this answer) and missed that there was a property specifically for removing the underline.

---

Below is an example of how to remove the underline. `:before` is used for the default and hover styling and `:after` is used for the focused styling, so the border needs to be removed for both of those cases.

The multiple ampersands (e.g. `"&&&:before"`) increase the [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of the rule so that it wins over the default styling (e.g. [`&:hover:not($disabled):before`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.4.2/packages/material-ui/src/Input/Input.js#L64)).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  underline: {
    "&&&:before": {
      borderBottom: "none"
    },
    "&&:after": {
      borderBottom: "none"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return <TextField defaultValue="default text" InputProps={{ classes }} />;
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit TextField underline]

Related answer: [How do I custom style the underline of Material-UI without using theme?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56023814/how-do-i-custom-style-the-underline-of-material-ui-without-using-theme/56026253#56026253)

Comment: Thank you, Ryan, very detailed  answer and that's exactly what i wanted !

Answer (score 175):

You can also use the `InputProps` prop on the TextField component to achieve this by setting the `disableUnderline` property to `true`.

```html
<TextField
  fullWidth
  placeholder="Search..."
  InputProps={{ disableUnderline: true }}
 />
```

Comment: The real answer

Comment: In case anyone check this for <Autocomplete, doing this disables the autocomplete dropdown as well. Hope this helps to someone.

Comment: @Arosha The issues with Autocomplete would be similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238786/material-ui-autocomplete-is-not-working-when-setting-textfield-inputprops/61239293#61239293).

Comment: @Arosha yes i also encountered the same issue, Autocomplete is not working and the only option of createMuiTheme worked for me

Comment: @H.Zao this is the simpliest answer

Comment: For me this works on Autocomplete but using `InputProps`, with uppercase

Comment: This did not work. Why?   https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-underline-forked-9nb87?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: Worked with capital "InputProps" not "inputProps"!

Comment: Just had to revert this back to `InputProps` as mentioned in comments. For future reference, lowercase `inputProps` targets the *attributes* of the input, not the props passed to the MUI component. [Documentation](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/)

Comment: @lawrence-witt .. thank you for the edit and the heads-up information

Comment: For Autocomplete `InputProps={{...params.InputProps, disableUnderline: true}} ` will show dropdown as well.