# Material Ui TextField remove bottom border

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, frontend, customization, textfield

i am using material ui for my project and this is my textField
[text field reality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMCDP.jpg)

as you can see there is an bottom border underline it, but i want to remove it completely, previously i usually use border: "0px" but i dont know how to customize it, this is what i want

[text field expectation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tnz4s.png)

thank for your time to help me out, highly appreciate your effort, hope you have a good day

you can edit in this codesandbox link: [codesanboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-odpv3?file=/demo.js)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I remove the underline of TextField from Material-UI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57914368/how-can-i-remove-the-underline-of-textfield-from-material-ui)

Comment: thank you, but probably i will use inputbase instead

Comment: Sure! Don't forget to accept the [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Answer (score 2):

for this case you can import InputBase from material-ui

```
import InputBase from '@material-ui/core/InputBase';
```

you can see your example at codesandbox [codesandboxlink](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-3pgy9?file=/demo.js)